# Characters defined using '\uxxxx' format display the wrong character

Tags: c++, unicode, character-encoding

I am using Dev C++, windows 7.

I am trying to print out non-ascii characters using:

```
char a='\uwxyz';
```

For example:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.UTF-8");
    char a='\u0041'; //Should display 'A'
    cout<<a<<endl;
    a='\u2639'; //Should display '☹'
    cout<<a<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

In this example, the capital A displays correctly. Using wxDev, simply nothing is displayed for the ☹ character. Using Dev (which I need to use for the final program), I would get an extended ascii character (It was a symbol with similar to ∥, but there are multiple symbols that look like that and I could not tell which it was).

In both Dev and wxDev, ☹ displays as ?.

I added the setlocale after some initial searches on how to correctly display unicode characters, but I have not found any solutions to this issue yet.

I cannot use a different compiler or modify system settings to make this work. (Yes, it is a school project. No, the special characters are not required for the project; I just want to make it look nicer.) If this cannot work without modifying such settings, that would be useful information too.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit: using Dev, not wxDev,

```
char a='\u0041'; //should be A
cout<<a;
```

I get an error: \u0041 is not a valid universal character

If I use wchar_t as the data type:

```
wchar_t a = '\u2639';
cout<<a<<endl;
```

The output is 39097.

Comment: `char a='\u2639'` is unlikely to do what you want, because `char` (by definition) is one byte, and `\u2639` cannot fit in one byte (at least when one byte is eight bits, as it almost always is). For alternatives, you might try Googling "wide character" or `wchar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Universal Character Names (UCNs) are a method of communicating to the compiler the character that you want to represent. As long as you can get the *basic source characters* to a compiler then every compiler will see the same UCN and therefore will see that you are representing the same character.

This is as opposed to writing the character literally in the source:

```
char a = '☹';
```

Since compilers are only required to support the basic source characters a compiler may not even be able to process this code. And what it actually sees depends on the *source encoding* the compiler uses. One compiler may see the character you want while another compiler sees

```
char a = 'Â☐¹';
```

However, simply because UCNs are able to specify the character to the compiler does not mean that:

- the compiler's *execution charset* contains that character or
- the datatype `char` can represent that character value

In your case the primary problem is that the *execution character set* is one of Windows' code pages (probably CP1252) which does not have the character '☹'. So when the compiler converts the character '☹' into the execution character set, the conversion produces '?' instead of what you want.

The execution character set for my compiler does include the character '☹', but it happens to have a multi-byte representation so my compiler says:

```
error: character too large for enclosing character literal type
    char a = '☹';
             ^
```

To really understand this topic you need to understand encodings, character sets, how these play into the C++ phases of translation, and how that relates to the compiler's processing of character and string literals. Also, locales really have nothing to do with any of this; locales deal with runtime behavior whereas your problem is entirely with your compiler's compile-time handling of encodings.

---

On a platform that uses UTF-8 everywhere the following works:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "☹\n";
}
```

Note that the above uses a string literal rather than a character literal, so that the character can expand to its multi-byte representation.

Unfortunately Windows does not support Unicode this way. On Windows it's more complicated:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cwchar>

int main() {
    wchar_t const *a = L"\u2639\n";
    DWORD numOfCharsWritten;
    WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), a, wcslen(a), &numOfCharsWritten, NULL);
}
```

Unfortunately even the above code is unlikely to display what you want, because the console on Windows typically is not configured to be able to display the Unicode character '☹'. Instead you might want to take a look at the OEM encoding used by your console (probably CP437), look up the encoding for a character you want, and then print out that value. For example CP437 has the character '☺' instead, and you could print that out like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "\x01\n"; // ☺ has the value 0x01 in CP 437
}
```

Comment: If you run console with `chcp 65001`, and change the font to something  less ancient than the default one, shouldn't `std::cout << "☹\n";` just work if the source file is saved in UTF-8 and the compiler can be configured to not do anything to it? It's just directly passing the source bytes through and the console can interpret them with code page 65001. The same idea works in PHP where you only have char* strings.

Comment: That would work, although preventing the compiler from converting between the source encoding and its execution encoding (by saving the file as UTF-8 without signature) would break wide character literals. And there's no other way to do it with VC++.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent explanation! It was even understandable too. I will see if I can fix up the code page, but if not, I at least understand why it does not work now.

Comment: @Esailija actually on second thought that still would not work when writing out to the console. It would work fine when writing to a file, but the Windows console will try to convert each individual byte from UTF-8. Since the individual bytes will all be partial UTF-8 sequences the console will just show a conversion error for each byte. You can, however, replaces your usage of `cout` with a usage of `puts` and get that to work.

Comment: @user2197013 unfortunately the code page that VC++ uses for the execution character set can only be configured by setting the system "encoding for non-Unicode programs" on the machine that compiles the code. And then on every machine you want to run the exe on you may have to set that machine's "encoding for non-Unicode programs" to the same code page. It's not very convenient.